# Pivot Table Toggle Calculation based on user pick

Tags: pivot-table, toggle, qlikview, calculation

I have a series of pivot tables that I'd like to allow a user to toggle between hours and days. The pick is captured in a variable - `vViewBy`

I've had success at toggling the values displayed in another pivot table that shows all games using:

```
= if( vViewBy='Hours', 
      round(Aggr(Sum([HOURS]), [GAME]),1),
      round(Aggr(Sum([HOURS])/24, [GAME]),1)
)
```

My problem is when I only want a subset of the data, games with `GAME_CAT = Sports`.  How do add in `vViewBy` to calculate YTD Hours or Days of Sport related Games?  I want to display the top 5 games.

`= if([GAME_CAT]='Sports',Num((Aggr(Sum([HOURS]), [GAME])),0),0)`

[image: Desired Toggle calculation results]

Comment: Why not just a List Box for [GAME_CAT] and then select 'Sports'? All the visualizations will then recalculate accordingly. Then you would have the flexibility to see any of the other categories on their own or compare across the categories without building new tables for each

Comment: It's what the customer wants...One table for overall, then top 5 for each category.  Everything in one view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list box doesn't work for what you want to do then putting the Set Analysis for the Sports category into the expression would look something like this

```
 = if( vViewBy='Hours', 
  round(Aggr(Sum({<[GAME_CAT]={'Sports'}>} [HOURS]), [GAME]),1),
  round(Aggr(Sum({<[GAME_CAT]={'Sports'}>}[HOURS])/24, [GAME]),1)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I needed.

Comment: Cool, please give me my magic internet points and mark this solved :) Thanks